# How to chain error in Promise in Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, promise

I'm currently writing an Ionic app and I would need to chain down error, but somehow I'm keep getting this

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]
```

when I try to reject the error. I suppose I must have been doing something wrong somewhere but I don't know how to do it. The error supposedly is only handled at the doSomething() method.

The structure of the code is like this:

```
sendRequest(...) {
    ...
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.post(this.server, body, {headers: header, withCredentials: true}).subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data);
      }, err => {
        return Promise.reject(err);
      });
    });
  }

procesRequest(...) {
    ...
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.sendRequest(...).then((data) => {
        resolve(data);
      }, (reason) => {
        return Promise.reject(reason);
      }).catch((error => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }));
    });
  }

doSomething {
    ...
    processRequest(...).then((data) => {
      this.showSuccessMessage();
    }, (err) => {
      this.showErrorMessage(err);
    }).catch((err) => {
      this.showErrorMessage(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Which angular version are you using?

Comment: It's Ionic 3 so my version is Angular 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic example is something like below:

```js
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var cleanRoom = false;
   if(!cleanRoom){
     reject('promise1 rejected');
    }
});
var promise2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   if(true){
     reject('promise2 rejected');
    }
});
function doSomething () {
 promise1.catch((rej) => {
     console.log(rej);
    });
   promise2.catch((rej) => {
     console.log(rej);
    });
}
doSomething();
```

Comment: So how would i receive the data from my http post request?

Comment: Also i'm not sure how I can pass variable from my outer function to the Promise